# Using GraphicsGrid for density plots with color scales

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, graphics, mathematical-optimization

I would like to arrange the density plots in a certain order using GraphicsGrid. But when using GraphicsGrid, there is problem with the color scale, it doesn't display completely. How should GraphicsGrid be written so that the color scales of the density plots are displayed correctly?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

f[B_] := B*(r^2 + z^2)*Sin[z]^2;

ff = Table[
  DensityPlot[f[B], {r, 0, 10}, {z, -5, 5}, FrameLabel -> {r, z}, 
   PlotLabel -> StringForm["B = ``", B], 
   ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotPoints -> 250, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 200], {B, {0, 5, 10, 25}}]

GraphicsGrid[{{ff[[1]], ff[[3]]}, {ff[[2]], ff[[4]]}}]
```

Comment: Add `ImageSize -> 550` to the `GraphicsGrid` or use `Grid` instead of `GraphicsGrid`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, thanks! It works

Answer (score 2):

Graphics and Inset give you more control, e.g.

```
{{f1, f3}, {f2, f4}} = {{ff[[1]], ff[[3]]}, {ff[[2]], ff[[4]]}};
{x, y} = {280, 220};
Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2 x, 2 y}],
  Inset[f1, {x/2, 2 y - y/2}, Center, x],
  Inset[f2, {2 x - x/2, 2 y - y/2}, Center, x],
  Inset[f3, {x/2, y/2}, Center, x],
  Inset[f4, {2 x - x/2, y/2}, Center, x]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2 x}, {0, 2 y}}, ImageSize -> 2 x]
```